# Compiling embedded CoffeeScript without installing the compiler?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

According to the [site](http://coffeescript.org/) you can compile inline CoffeeScript using [this](http://coffeescript.org/extras/coffee-script.js). How can I compile embedded .coffee files, though? Those that are sourced externally like:

```
<script src="js/script.coffee"></script>
```

I tried adding `coffeescript` to the file type but I get this:

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type
>   text/plain:
>   "file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/public/%E6%A1%8C%E9%9D%A2/coffetest/js/script.coffee".
>   index.html:23 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/public/%E6%A1%8C%E9%9D%A2/coffetest/js/script.coffee.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use the attribute "type" for your coffee-scripts tags.

```
<script src="..." type=”text/coffeescript”></script>
<script type=”text/coffeescript”>...</script>
```